# How to find the difference in hours between two dates dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: regex, date, datetime, google-sheets, duration

I have two dates in cells

```
A1=05.11.2021 18:16
B1=05.11.2021 20:16
```

I need to find difference in hours between two dates. Result should be (B1-A1)=2  I can't find an answer on the Internet, I ask for help.

Comment: Format result cell as ```h``` and you will get ```2```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=TEXT((DATE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(B1, "\d{4}"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(B1, "\.(\d+)\."),
 REGEXEXTRACT(B1, "^\d+"))+INDEX(SPLIT(B1, " "),,2))-(DATE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d{4}"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\.(\d+)\."), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "^\d+"))+INDEX(SPLIT(A1, " "),,2)), "[h]")
```

[image]

arrayformula:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(TEXT((DATE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B, "\d{4}"),
 REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B, "\.(\d+)\."),
 REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B, "^\d+"))+INDEX(SPLIT(B1:B, " "),,2))-(DATE(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d{4}"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\.(\d+)\."), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^\d+"))+INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A, " "),,2)), "[h]")))
```

---

shorter:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(TEXT(
 REGEXREPLACE(B1:B, "(\d+).(\d+).(\d{4})", "$2/$1/$3")-
 REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "(\d+).(\d+).(\d{4})", "$2/$1/$3"), "[h]")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @player0, do you think `=hour(REGEXREPLACE(B1, "\.", "/") - REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\.", "/"))` yields the same answer with your answer in all cases? I'm not sure if my approach has problems in some cases. I haven't considered it until I saw your answer and now I doubted mine, haha.

Comment: @NaziA it worked in my localized sheet, but then I realized OP asks for duration

Comment: I see, also it gets the total number of hours. Thanks for the more clarified answer.

Comment: @NaziA https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmw7Q.png

Comment: error shows `/` is the delimiter. If it is `.`, i think it should work properly. And the formula only works if cell values are purely text. I think that is already a proper date formatted to `.` as delimiter

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT:

As what @basic mentioned in the above comment, you can format the cell where your output goes or use `text` with `h` for hour difference and `[h]` for the whole duration in hours (got from Cooper's answer). See usage and difference below:

#### Text:

```
=text(B1-A1, "h")
```

or

```
=text(B1-A1, "[h]")
```

[image: diff]

#### Update:

- Make sure your Date Times uses proper delimiters. `/` and `-` are acceptable (e.g. `5/11/2021 18:16:00` or `5-11-2021 18:16:00`). (This depends entirely on your locale.)

[image: delimiter]

- If you want to show it having `.` as delimiter, just use a custom Date Time format and use `.` as its delimiter.
- Using custom format:

  - [image: custom]
- Actual value vs Display value:

  - [image: vs]
- If you don't want to do any changes to the date time and want to have it as text, then replace them using `regexreplace` before using them in `text`.

#### RegexReplace:

```
=text(REGEXREPLACE(B1, "\.", "/") - REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\.", "/"), "h")
```

or

```
=text(REGEXREPLACE(B1, "\.", "/") - REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\.", "/"), "[h]")
```

[image: regex]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t work. It throw next error "Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '05.11.2021 20:16' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."

Comment: I updated my answer @DmitriyKupriyanov

Comment: Big thanks @NaziA And I have additional question. Do you know why is it doesn’t work properly =text(NOW()-REGEXREPLACE(A2, "\.", "/"), "d") ?

Comment: Your welcome @DmitriyKupriyanov. If `A2`'s delimiter is `.` and is purely a text, it should work and return how many days. Can you share a sample sheet? It might be that your `A2` is already a date or the delimiter is not `.`. If `A2` is already a date, then no need using `REGEXREPLACE`.